# Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(Int)' in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a WebView in a Fragment which will refer to the WebView element I have created in XML for the fragment, but I get an error (Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(Int)') How would I make this work?

```
public class location_Fragment extends Fragment {

private WebView webView;

View rootview;

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);
    return rootview;

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("URL HERE");
    return webView;
    }
}
```

Comment: write like this:  webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following

```
rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);
webView = (WebView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("URL HERE");
return rootview;
}
```